# How do I grant users rights to only see a Project Team Site and not other items in PWA such as Project Center, Resource Center, etc?

Tags: project-online, pwa

How do I grant users rights to only see a Project Team Site and not other items in PWA such as Project Center, Resource Center, etc?

I only want users to be able to see Their tasks, Issues, risks, timesheets etc, from the main page and only be able to drill down on specific projects I grants them access to.

I am using Sharepoint Permission mode.

Thank you.